Restart graphics driver in Ubuntu
Windows has the Win + Ctrl + Shift + R keyboard shortcut.  Is there anything equivalent for Ubuntu?
I have a Windows Desktop and Ubuntu laptop that I am using through a KVM on multiple monitors.  When I start up Ubuntu with the KVM switched to the Ubuntu laptop the video is fine, my large monitors are displaying everything in the proper resolution and scale.  For example the display settings window shows resolution is 2560 x 1440 and scale is 100%, and all of the window elements are nice and small on screen.
If I switch away from the laptop and come back, when the displays return, the apparent scaling is much higher and all elements are very large despite the Ubuntu display settings window showing them set at 100%.  I am hoping that resetting the graphics driver and re-initializing the displays might fix the issue.
Edit: Forgot to mention that on switch back it also does not return primary display to the correct display, but rather leaves it on the laptop screen.
